# Quote on awareness

Tags: quotes

I am in search of a quote or a sentence that exhibits the importance of awareness and tries to convey the fact that how the act of knowing something can lead to a huge difference.

Comment: "Knowing is half the battle" perhaps?

Comment: And spelling is the other half.

Answer (score 0):

There are many such quotes I'm sure, my favourite is probably:

> If you know the enemy and know yourself, you need not fear the result of a hundred battles.
>
> ~[Sun Tzu](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/17976-if-you-know-the-enemy-and-know-yourself-you-need)